# Facebook login in from a third party static website then redirect to my rails app website

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-oauth

My rails app has many clients with separate data. Apart from admin users for each client using a regular password login from my site I want a public Facebook login where each public user is associated with a particular customer.

My plan is to have each client include a Facebook login on their own static website and use the state parameter to set the client id. After the Facebook authorization the public user should be redirected to my rails site.

Can I do this? The only documentation I can find involves a link to auth/facebook from my rails site, however, I don't want to allow users to initiate a login from my site.

Comment: Facebook login on websites ties an app to one domain (or subdomains) - so using the same app for login from different domains will not work. (Although you could have the login button on the other sites link to your app page first, and then handle login there.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I will do. You should have put your comment up as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook login on websites ties an app to one domain (or subdomains) - so using the same app for login from different domains will not work. (Although you could have the login button on the other sites link to your app page first, and then handle login there.)